# Compare SQL Server Schema across 2 different domains

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

I am trying to compare 2 databases across domains.  Our environment is in 2 different domains for security reasons and we are trying to compare the existing database structure to our newly transferred database structure using schema compare and/or database compare tools.  However, since the new database is on a different domain we cannot use the tool (get login failure on 2nd database).  We have used the runas command to connect SSMS 2012 to the new database structure and that works.  How can I do the same thing using the compare tools?

Be aware we do have identity based firewall rules that open port 1433 between the 2 domains.

Comment: if possible, you can export the table structure to sql file and then run the sql on a newly created local database and then do a schema compare locally

Comment: are you using sql server authentication or windows authentication? i think for the one on the different domain you would need sql server auth or some kind of impersonation?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a tool supporting Windows Authentication for 2 accounts at the same time. Here are some things that might work though:

- Setup a SQL account on one of the servers, and connect your comparison tool to that SQL account and the other domain account via Windows Auth (ie: RedGate SQL Compare, Visual Studio database project, etc)
- Use a more advanced schema comparison tool (Idera or RedGate) to compare snapshots/backups/etc instead of the direct database

  - RedGate SQL Compare - Grab backups of the prod and non-prod database, then have the tool compare the 2 backups
  - Idera SQL Comparison Toolset - Connect to first database, take schema snapshot, then compare that snapshot to the second database